# how to write a .wav file with large number of channels using soundfile

Tags: python-3.x, wav

Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Non-audio_data says that the maximum number of channels of a .wav file is 65535. However, when I tried to create a file with more than 1024 channels using *soundfile* (https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#soundfile.SoundFile):

```
import soundfile as sf
outfile = sf.SoundFile( 'C:/fname.wav', 'w', samplerate=44100, channels=1025 )
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: Error opening 'C:/fname.wav': Format not recognised.
```

What is going on? Is it possible to exceed this 1024-limit, and how?

Comment: use `C:\\fname.wav`

Comment: That's not a problem: when I change the number of channels to 1024, it works fine

Comment: Try to open the file with some hex editor and check the header.